# how can I Deserialize emoji in json in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, emoji

I have a json file that include emoji when I want to deserialize it , it could not deserialize emoji to string. 
my code is:

```
var mystring ={"message":"jjasdajdasjdj laslla aasdasd ssdfdsf!!! \u{1F3FD}", "updated_time":"2015-04-14T22:37:13+0000", "id":"145193995506_148030368559"}

FaceBookIdea ideaDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaceBookIdea>((mystring).ToString());
```

the error is :

```
{"Input string was not in a correct format."}
```

when I remove emoji it works well.

Thank a lot for your help

Comment: Show us the definition of FaceBookIdea.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that this portion of your message string does not conform to the [JSON standard](http://json.org/):

```
"\u{1F3FD}"
```

According to the standard, `\u four-hex-digits` represents a unicode character literal given by the hex value of its code point.  Your string `\u{1F3FD}` with its curly braces does not conform to this convention, and so Json.NET throws an exception upon trying to parse it.  You will see a similar error if you upload your JSON to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Thus it would seem, to fix your JSON to make it conform to the standard, you need to format your character like `\uXXXX` using the appropriate 4 hex digits.  However, your character, [`U+1F3FD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3fd/index.htm), is larger than 0xFFFF and does not exist on the Unicode [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).  It cannot be represented as a single 4-digit hex number.  c# (and [utf-16 in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF)) represents such Unicode characters as [surrogate pairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8k5611at%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) -- pairs of two two-byte chars.  You will need to do the same here.  The [UTF-16 (hex)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3fd/index.htm) representation of your character is

```
0xD83C 0xDFFD
```

Thus your JSON character needs to be:

```
\uD83C\uDFFD
```

And for your entire string:

```
{"message":"jjasdajdasjdj laslla aasdasd ssdfdsf!!! \uD83C\uDFFD", "updated_time":"2015-04-14T22:37:13+0000", "id":"145193995506_148030368559"}
```

Comment: you can find complete list of emoji as surrogate pairs [here](https://github.com/shanraisshan/EmojiCodeSheet)