# JSON String gets cutoff When emoji is in data

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, emoji

I have a VB.Net Webservice that returns data is a JSON string. Some of the data returned might have an EMOJI in it. When I return data that does not have an EMOJI in it the data come back fine.

Like this -

```
[
  {
    "ImgID": "150",
    "ImgDesc": "Added to your portfolio",
    "PublicID": "c0lbquvzitd3igohfh7x",
    "ImgURL": "test.com",
    "LikeCount": "0",
    "CommentCnt": "2",
    "PickCount": "",
    "ServerUpdateDate": "1\/17\/2016 3:13:21 PM",
    "UserName": "Deathstarspa",
    "ProfileImgID": "hqhoiohfckzldgpdem6k",
    "Location": "Chester County, PA, USA",
    "dltflg": "False",
    "PortName": "2 0 1 6 | M E N S",
    "Categories": "Blowouts"
  },
  {
    "ImgID": "151",
    "ImgDesc": "Stone cold",
    "PublicID": "udecff1bi0ymhewp1qlv",
    "ImgURL": "Test.com",
    "LikeCount": "0",
    "CommentCnt": "0",
    "PickCount": "",
    "ServerUpdateDate": "1\/17\/2016 3:17:26 PM",
    "UserName": "Deathstarspa",
    "ProfileImgID": "hqhoiohfckzldgpdem6k",
    "Location": "Chester County, PA, USA",
    "dltflg": "False",
    "PortName": "2 0 1 6 | M E N S",
    "Categories": "Test"
  }
]
```

If the data has an emoji anywhere in the sting the string gets cutoff at the very end.

It does not matter where the emoji is in the data.

Like -

```
[
  {
    "ImgID": "161",
    "ImgDesc": "Bed ?????",
    "PublicID": "gnw6ooo04ls21kqq8doo",
    "ImgURL": "test.com",
    "LikeCount": "0",
    "CommentCnt": "0",
    "PickCount": "",
    "ServerUpdateDate": "2\/11\/2016 8:18:03 PM",
    "UserName": "Deathstarspa",
    "ProfileImgID": "hqhoiohfckzldgpdem6k",
    "Location": "Chester County, PA, USA",
    "dltflg": "False",
    "PortName": "Bed Pics",
    "Categories": "Blowouts,Treatments"
  },
  {
    "ImgID": "162",
    "ImgDesc": "Bed ?????",
    "PublicID": "lrdxpvwxoq5zxpkagamo",
    "ImgURL": "test.com",
    "LikeCount": "0",
    "CommentCnt": "0",
    "PickCount": "",
    "ServerUpdateDate": "2\/11\/2016 8:18:05 PM",
    "UserName": "Deathstarspa",
    "ProfileImgID": "hqhoiohfckzldgpdem6k",
    "Location": "Chester County, PA, USA",
    "dltflg": "False",
    "PortName": "Test Pics"
```

Although you cannot see the Emojis in the ImgDesc piece the `?????` represent the emoji. So the record with `ImgID 161` is complete, but the record with `ImgID` of `162` get cutoff at `"Test Pics,"`. If I remove the emoji from the ImgDesc then the data come back fine.

I am working with `VB.NET` and I have the `Newtonsoft.Json dll` referenced.

Is there something I need to do so the **emojis** do not cause issues?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/34139312/1070452

Comment: Possible problems include: 1) You are downloading the JSON using the wrong encoding, as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716470) for example.  2) The JSON is wrongly encoded on the sending side, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34139312/1070452) for example.  For us to help more, we would need to see a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code where you download and deserialize the JSON, and the complete byte stream or string that you receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to properly encode the emoji, per the JSON standard. See the related answer below:

[how can I Deserialize emoji in json in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34139312/1070452)